# SharePoint 2013 REST API . Filter system folders and expanding folders and files.

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint

I'm trying to get all Folders and Files with one API call. 
I'm using `$expand` for this

```
/sites/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('MyDocuments')?$expand= "Folders/ListItemAllFields,Files/ListItemAllFields,Folders/Files/ListItemAllFields,Folders/Folders/ListItemAllFields,Folders/Folders/Files/ListItemAllFields"
```

This is works just as expected. 
But along with response I got few system folders , like `Forms`

I tried this approach https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138135/get-all-files-and-folders-in-one-call?noredirect=1&lq=1
So I added : `$filter` to my request.

```
/sites/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('MyDocuments')?$expand="Folders/ListItemAllFields,Files/ListItemAllFields,Folders/Files/ListItemAllFields,Folders/Folders/ListItemAllFields,Folders/Folders/Files/ListItemAllFields"?$filter="Folder/Name ne 'Attachments' and Folder/Name ne 'Item' and Folder/Name ne 'Forms'"
```

But it looks like filter does not affect response at all. 
Is there is any way I can use expand and filter in one request ? 
How can I filter response to remove System Folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the filter expression is valid but it is getting ignored in this case.

```
/sites/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('MyDocuments')?$filter=<expr>
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
                  $filter expression could not be applied per item resource 
            (GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl function returns a Folder resource here)
```

`$filter` query option is supported per collection of resources only.

---

Instead i would suggest to utilize the following [`ListItemCollection` resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItemCollection) endpoint:

```
url: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<title>')/items
method: GET
```

It returns the collection of items ([`ListItem` resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItem) type). Using `$expand` query option all the files along with folders will be included in the result:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<title>')/items?$expand=Folder,File
```

> Note: no *system* files and folders will be included in result

Comment: Thanks that works. Unfortunately this approach does not give me a content structure. This API returns me a array of items , so I can't get information about Folder and Files structure from it without doing extra calls.

Comment: @vadim how to get all document libraries, folders and files for a site(root or other)?

Answer (score 0):

Check your REST URL.

Here you have written :

**?$expand="Folders/ListItemAllFi_____________ListItemAllFields"?$filter=**

Here it should be **&$filter** instead in place of **?$filter**

Try below URL :

```
/sites/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('MyDocuments')?$expand="Folders/ListItemAllFields,Files/ListItemAllFields,Folders/Files/ListItemAllFields,Folders/Folders/ListItemAllFields,Folders/Folders/Files/ListItemAllFields"&$filter="Folder/Name ne 'Attachments' and Folder/Name ne 'Item' and Folder/Name ne 'Forms'"
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it was just typo. I have correct URL. Still has this issue and get back all System folders along with my folders.